# Error al insertar y modificar al mismo tiempo en php y mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy intentando insertar registros en mi base de datos y al mismo tiempo hacer un UPDATE en otra tabla de la misma base de datos, inserta todos los registros muy bien pero arroja los siguientes mensajes:

Este es mi formulario:

```
<form action="procesar.php" method="POST">  
<input type="text" id="refe" name="refe" value="<?php echo $elid?>" readonly="readonly" />  
<input type="text" name="estatus" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" name="hora_ini" value="<?php echo $horatwo;?>" readonly="readonly" />                    
<input type="text" id="estado_kal" name="estado_kal" value="En progreso" readonly="readonly" />

<table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">POSICIÓN</th>
                                    <th scope="col">TRABAJO A REALIZAR</th>
                                    <th scope="col">HORA INICIO</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
<?php
$valorTrabajos = $datostwo['trabajos_llan'];
$trabajos = explode(',', $valorTrabajos);

foreach($trabajos as $trabajo) {

?>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
    <th scope="row">
    <select name="posatendi[]" required>   
    <option value="<?php echo $trabajo;?>"><?php echo $trabajo;?></option>
    </select></th>
<?php
   $sql7 = "SELECT id_trabajo,nom_trabajo FROM para_trabajos";
   $result7=mysqli_query($conn,$sql7);
?>                                   
    <td style="font-size:12px;">
    <select name="tipotrabajo[]" required>
    <option></option> 

    <?php

    while ($row7 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result7))
    {
    ?>  
        <option value="<?=$row7['nom_trabajo']?>"><?=$row7['nom_trabajo']?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select></td>

                                    <td><input type="time" name="horainicio[]" value="<?php echo $horatwo;?>" required ></td>
                                </tr>                           
                            </tbody>

<?php   
}
?>
    </table>    
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Iniciar Trabajos" id="btn_inicia"/> 
</form>
```

Este es mi procesar.php

```
<?php
  include "conexiones.php";

$refe=$_POST['refe'];
$estatus=$_POST['estatus'];
$hora_ini=$_POST['hora_ini'];
$estado_kal=$_POST['estado_kal'];

$posatendi=$_POST['posatendi']; 
$tipotrabajo=$_POST['tipotrabajo']; 
$horainicio=$_POST['horainicio'];       


for($i = 0; $i < count($tipotrabajo); $i++){

       $refe[$i];
       $posatendi[$i];
       $tipotrabajo[$i];
       $horainicio[$i];
       $estatus[$i];


    $sql="INSERT INTO p_atendidas(refe,posatendi,tipotrabajo,horainicio,estatus)
       VALUES ('".$refe."','".$posatendi[$i]."','".$tipotrabajo[$i]."','".$horainicio[$i]."','".$estatus."')";
       $res=mysqli_query($cn,$sql);     

}

{
 ModificarProducto($_POST['refe'], $_POST['hora_ini'], $_POST['estado_kal'] );

        function ModificarProducto($refe, $hora_ini, $estado_kal)
        {
        include 'conexion.php';
        $sentencia="UPDATE trabajos SET 
        refe='".$refe."'
        , hora_ini='".$hora_ini."'
        , estado_kal='".$estado_kal."'
        WHERE refe='".$refe."' ";
        $conexion->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al actualizar datos".mysqli_error($conexion));
        }  




    if($res){
           echo "<script>alert('El trabajo inicio exitosamente!')
           window.location='tllantasactuali.php?dato=$refe';</script>";

        }else{
            die("Error".mysqli_error($cn));
        }       

    }





?>
```

El procesar funciona bien, realiza el insert y el update sin problemas pero siempre me da estos mensajes:

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\modulos\agregar_ptrabajos.php on line 16

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\modulos\agregar_ptrabajos.php on line 20
CORRECTO!

Que podría estar haciendo mal? y de que manera podría corregir?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Te diste cuenta que $refe en values esta pasado como string y es un array

$sql="INSERT INTO p_atendidas(refe,posatendi,tipotrabajo,horainicio,estatus)
       VALUES ('".$refe."','".$posatendi[$i]."','".$tipotrabajo[$i]."','".$horainicio[$i]."','".$estatus."')";
       $res=mysqli_query($cn,$sql);

Comment: Arregla la respuesta poniendo el código con sangría. Selecciona todo el código que has escrito y seguidamente pulsa en {} (pre code). @ilogic65

Comment: Hola @ilogic65 de igual forma no funciona realizando la corrección que indicas, la variable refe debo dejarla asi porque de lo contrario solo me guarda ese valor en el primer registro.